# Reducing the logic in if-else code using Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

My function somewhat look like this and I want to reduce my code

```
function name(){
//some coding part 
if (!data && value.type != "doc") {
    tempDir = tempDir + value.type;
  } else {
    if (data && value.type != "doc") {
    tempDir = tempDir + value.type;
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any possibility I can reduce my if-else logic

Comment: Seems like the logic is the same in both branches of your loop. Why not `if (value.type != 'doc')`

Comment: You are assigning the same value to `tempDir` in both places, I assume this is not intended. Could you please update your question, if that's the case?

Comment: Let's say I flip a coin. If it lands on head *and* it's lunch time, I'd go for lunch. But if it lands on tail *and* it's lunch time, I'd go for lunch. It seems like I don't need to be flipping the coin to decide whether I'd be having lunch or not.

Answer (score 4):

Checking for `data` or `!data` seems irrelevant here, so I believe this could be reduced to

```
function name() {
  if (value.type != "doc") {
    tempDir = tempDir + value.type;
  }
}
```